# Flutter: Display all available Calendars from mobile and add event to selected calendar

Tags: android, swift, flutter, calendar

I want to display all the calendar options present on the mobile (google calendar, outlook calendar, ios native calendar) and when the user selects any particular option the event should be added to the calendar.

Is this possible in Flutter or the same thing can be achieved in iOS and android?